# detect.tflite failure converting TF model to TFlite

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api

I am using my mac, running Catalina 10.15.5, with Python 2.7.17, running Tensorflow 1.15.3 from source, installed using pip, not in Anaconda, and my bazel version is 0.26.1.

I am trying to convert my custom model on ssd_mobilenet_v3_small_coco to TFlite, following this tutorial: [On step 3](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi) but cannot convert my tflite_graph.pb to detect.tflite using this line:

```
bazel run --config=opt tensorflow/lite/toco:toco -- --input_file=/Users/jp3spinelli/Desktop/models/research/object_detection/TFLite_model/tflite_graph.pb --output_file=/Users/jp3spinelli/Desktop/models/research/object_detection/TFLite_model/detect.tflite --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor --output_arrays=TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3 --inference_type=FLOAT --allow_custom_ops
```

I keep running into this error (I only included the last bit because it's quite lengthy):

```
WARNING: /Users/jp3spinelli/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2455:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:lib_internal_impl: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/lib/strings:proto_text_util.cc' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
WARNING: /Users/jp3spinelli/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2455:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:lib_internal_impl: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/lib/strings:scanner.cc' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
WARNING: /Users/jp3spinelli/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:2455:12: in srcs attribute of cc_library rule //tensorflow/core:lib_internal_impl: please do not import '//tensorflow/core/lib/strings:strcat.cc' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there
INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/toco/toco
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.472s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/toco/toco '--input_file=/Users/jp3spinelli/Desktop/models/research/object_detection/TFLite_model/tflite_graph.pb' '--output_file=/Users/jp3spinelli/Desktop/models/research/object_detection/TFLite_model/detect.tflite' '--input_shapes=1,300,300,3' '--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor' '--output_arrays=TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_DetectioINFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
2020-07-21 18:03:47.675656: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:659] Converting unsupported operation: TFLite_Detection_PostProcess
2020-07-21 18:03:47.691874: F tensorflow/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:1669] Check failed: input_array_dims[i] == input_array_proto.shape().dims(i) (320 vs. 300)
Abort trap: 6
```

It is creating a file, but it has zero bytes so I know something is wrong.
I am working out of my tensorflow directory, which is in my home directory. One weird thing I noticed is that the path to my "models" folder on my Desktop says it starts in "iCloud Drive" not "Users."

Please let me know how to fix this, I am new with coding so I need some step-by-step instructions. Thanks!

Comment: The shape of the input tensor present in the graph does not match the `input_shapes` given. So try changing the `input_shapes` to `1,320,320,3`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should set output_arrays between '' as a String, try to run something like this:

```
bazel run --config=opt tensorflow/lite/toco:toco -- \
--input_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/tflite_graph.pb \
--output_file=$OUTPUT_DIR/detect.tflite \
--input_shapes=1,300,300,3 \
--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \
--output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'  \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--allow_custom_ops
```